# AsyncTask android to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have implemented an AsyncTask to get values of a web service and store them into an array, but something I am doing wrong because it says that "Invalid index 0, size is 0". The object "dia" is not well created. Here is my code:

```
private class GetValue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        metereologia = new ArrayList<DiaTemperatura>();

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
               eventos = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < eventos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = eventos.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject temp = c.getJSONObject(TAG_TEMP);
                    String max = temp.getString(TAG_MAX);
                    String min = temp.getString(TAG_MIN);

                    String humedad = c.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);

                    JSONObject weather = c.getJSONObject(TAG_WEATHER);
                    //String main = weather.getString(TAG_MAIN);
                    //String description = weather.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                    DiaTemperatura dia= new DiaTemperatura();


                    dia.setMyText(max);

                    metereologia.add(dia);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();



          TextView mitext = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temperatura);
          mitext.setText(metereologia.get(0).getMyText());


    }
}
```

Comment: on which line error showing ?

Comment: Please post your logcat error along with your json response.

Comment: at this line " temperatura.setText(metereologia.get(0).getTem_max());" Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in the metereologia so when you try to get it with `(metereologia.get(0).getMyText()`, it results in an error, `"Invalid index 0, size is 0"`.

Comment: Yes it I know but I don´t know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you must be declaring `metereologia` outside your AsyncTask, then initialising and populating it in the task.  This is not quite the correct way to use it.  Your AsyncTask should *return* the result of its computation.  You'll need to declare your task as:

```
private class GetValue extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<DiaTemperatura>> {
...
@Override
protected List<DiaTemperatura> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    List<DiaTemperatura>  metereologia = new ArrayList<DiaTemperatura>();
    ...
    return metereologia;
}
```

and thus onPostExecute becomes:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<DiaTemperatura> metereologia) {
```

I think that's right, it's off the top of my head...

Answer (score 0):

Your error must be in the line `mitext.setText(metereologia.get(0).getMyText());` Its will go for finding the value at the index 0 in your `metereologia` which its is not getting.

You can not directly set the value of your whole arraylist in such a way. You need to loop for the value whichever you want to set in your `TextView`.

Comment: but if I want only the value of the first element of the array why can´t I do like that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the metereologia so when you try to get it with (metereologia.get(0).getMyText(), it results in an error, *`"Invalid index 0, size is 0"`*.

1) For doing check work -

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

          TextView mitext = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temperatura);

          String content = "";

          if(metereologia.size() == 0)
          {
             //a check that your metereologia size is 0.

          }

          for(int i=0;i<metereologia.size();i++)
             content = content + metereologia.get(i).getMyText();

          mitext.setText(content);
         }
      }
```

2) To get the value right-

More convenient way is to return the object `metereologia` from background and pass it to postExecute method and then process.This is explained by @dave.c.

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<DiaTemperatura> metereologia) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

              TextView mitext = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.temperatura);

              String content = "";

              if(metereologia.size() == 0)
              {
                 //a check that your metereologia size is 0.

              }

              for(int i=0;i<metereologia.size();i++)
                 content = content + metereologia.get(i).getMyText();

              mitext.setText(content);
             }
          }
```

Comment: I hope that it is not my error. The problem is that "DiaTemperatura dia= new DiaTemperatura();" not works because I have debugged and does´t do this step. metereologia.get(i).getMyText(); is the same that metereologia.get(0).getMyText(); and I only want to rescue the first value. Thanks

Comment: Check the update. You need to pass the object to post method.